# Orion-ld Subscribe to all entities

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Can i subscribe to all updates from any entity that Orion-LD receive?
If yes what will a minimum example for it?

I have tried different option for entities attribute when i POST at orionld/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/

- "entities": [{"type": "*"}],
- "entities": [{"type": "Entity"}],
- "entities": [{"idPattern": ".*", "type": ".*"}],

Answer (score 0):

Right now the entity type is mandatory in NGSI-LD subscriptions.
That said, we recently discussed this in ETSI ISG CIM where the NGSI-LD API is defined and a decision has been made to allow for a "*" value of the entity type, matching all entity types.
This will most probably be be made official in the next release (v1.8.1) of the NGSI-LD API spec - early 2024.
The new feature will soon be implemented in the Orion-LD context broker. Hopefully before the end of this month, October 2023.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment The [ETSI spec](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.07.01_60/gs_cim009v010701p.pdf) section **5.2.8 EntityInfo** defines the options `id`, `idPattern` and `type`, so you cannot currently subscribe on `type` using a wildcard.

However, you can already use the  `/ngsi-ld/v1/types` endpoint to retrieve a list of every available Entity `type`, so you could retrieve all types (which returns `XXX`, `YYY`, `ZZZ` for example and create a subscription holding an array of EntityInfo elements as shown

```bash
curl -L -X GET 'http://context-broker/ngsi-ld/v1/types
```

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'http://context-broker/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/ld+json' \
--data-raw '{
  "description": "Notify me of all changes",
  "type": "Subscription",
  "entities": [{"type": "XXX"}, {"type": "YYY"}, {"type": "ZZZ"}],
  ... etc
   "@context": "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld"
}'
```